# How to generate .jtl file in jmeter with unique name?

Tags: jmeter

I have a doubt.
I want to create .jtl file with uniqe name in `yy-mm-dd-time` format.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use JMeter listener to write JTL file, you can use [time](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) function (and put it into filename parameter of listener) like:

```
${__time(yy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss)}.jtl
```

It also has shortcuts that you may want to use.

If you want to create JTL via `-l` command line option, you can use usual command line possibilities. For example in linux you can do:

```
sh jmeter.sh -n -t "TestPlan.jmx" -l $(date -d "today" +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S").jtl
```

Comment: I used this one : JTLLOG-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%@%time:~0,2%h%time:~3,2%m%time:~6,2%s%.jtl

Comment: Does not work, date: illegal option -- d and a empty name .jtl is generated